# Floating / Moving text content in a div

Tags: css, css-position

I have two divs one being a child to another. I wish my parent div which extends throughout the page to scroll. But the text upon it to remain fix from the top.
Here is the sample image :-
I want the background image of the background to be gray and that parent div will extend to the end of the page. The text present is on another div. I want this text to be always at the same position from the top of the screen. This actually acts as navigation for my website.

How can this be done ??

[image: main div structure]

Comment: Can you post some example markup? Try http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be what you are looking for

```
#nav {position:fixed; top: 30px;}
```

(no support for ie6)